# How to parse numbers from an array in codes like this?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I need to parse numbers from codes like this:

```
p1 <- c(1, 2, 100, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p2 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p30 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p300 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 2, 1, 0)
more variables starts with p...
other codes...
```

The results are like this:

```
1 2 100 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 2 1 0
```

in which each row represent an array of a variable.

I tried `sed` and `awk`, but doesn't work out it. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've tried. It looks to me like it should be trivial with `sed` -- remove everything up to `(`, and remove `,` and `)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do ... do you have text that looks like the first box, and you are trying to use sed or awk to produce the results in the second box?  Or do you actually need to parse the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU sed (for -r and EREs):

```
$ cat file
p1 <- c(1, 2, 100, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p2 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p30 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p300 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 2, 1, 0)

$ sed -r 's/.*\(|[,)]//g' file
1 2 100 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

awk one-liner:

```
kent$  awk -F'[()]' '{gsub(/, */," ",$2)}$0=$2' file
1 2 100 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 2 1 0
```

Comment: `$0=$2` nice trick! Or an even shorter version: `awk -F'[()]' '{$0=$2;gsub(/, */," ")}1'`

Comment: @TrueY u r a golfer :)  `awk -F'[()]' '{gsub(/, */," ")}$0=$2'`

Comment: @TrueY shortest I could get `awk -F'(' 'gsub(/,|)/,s)&&$0=$2'` with just `awk`

Comment: @sudo_O: Definitely +1!!! I have a two chars shorter version `awk -F\( 'gsub(/,|)/,s),$0=$2'`. :). Thanks for the `|`! I thought it works only in `(...)`. Also thanks for the `/[][]/`!

Comment: @sudo_O I assume that there could be multi spaces after the comma. If we skip that part, just based on the example in the question. the one-liner could be written like this:`awk 'gsub(/.*\(|,|)/,l)'`

Comment: @Kent yes of course golfed solution aren't going to be robust. Seems you won with `awk 'gsub(/.*\(|,|)/,l)'`!

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and `tr` for readability ;-)

```
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' file | tr -d ','
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have it in file t.txt:

```
$ grep ^p t.txt|sed 's/.*[(]//; s/[)].*//; s/,//g'

1 2 100 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `bash` without calling external programmes. A `bash` one-liner :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read v; do v=${v#*(}; v=${v%)*}; echo ${v//, / }; done<<XXX
p1 <- c(1, 2, 100, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p2 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p30 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 0.12, 0.03, 0)
p300 <- c(100, 200, 1, 23, 2, 1, 0)
XXX
```

Output:

```
1 2 100 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 0.12 0.03 0
100 200 1 23 2 1 0
```